# Why is a regular razor not allowed while some electric ones are permitted

Tags: halacha, minhag, shaving

According to [this article](http://www.aish.com/atr/Electric_Shavers.html?mobile=yes) it is not allowed to shave with a regular razor while it is allowed to use an electric razor as well as a depilatory (i.e., a chemical substance used to destroy the hair in order to remove hair as well as prevent future unwanted hair growth). The reason given is that shaving pulls the hair taught and destroys the beard. If the beard can still regrow, unlike the result of continual usage of depilatory, how is the beard considered to be destroyed anymore than after using an electric razor?

Also if shaving against the grain (i.e., cutting the hair opposite to the natural direction of hair growth) pulls hair taught and cuts it below the skin why wouldn’t shaving with the grain be allowed as the hair and skin would not then be pulled taught?

Thank you for any insight or explanation.

Comment: As far as I’m aware not all electric shavers are permitted, for the very reason you cite about shaving against the grain. The main thing is that one may cut his beard with anything which will not destroy the root and may not cut his beard with anything which will destroy the root.

Comment: @DonielF thank you for your response, but shaving with the grain does not destroy the root as the hair can still grow back. I don’t see why it’s not allowed to use a regular razor while these other methods are permitted. Shaving with the grain is no more destructive to the beard than shaving with an electric razor both permit the beard to grow back healthily and normally.

Comment: Halachically there is no distinction between completely destroying the root and cutting below the skin.

Comment: @DonielF but a depilatory would destroy the root over time . Also shaving with the grain cuts hair at the level of the skin since the skin is no pulled taught in the process as it is when one is shaving against the grain

Comment: At the level of the skin isn’t a problem. The halachic root is anything *below* the skin. Only cutting that is a problem.

Comment: @DonielF So why wouldn’t shaving with the grain with a regular razor be permissible if it doesn’t cut below the skin ?

Comment: I’d imagine it’s forbidden lest someone come to cut against the grain.

Comment: It seems that there are some scientific terms used consistently in this discussion. I'd recommend that OP, or, for that matter, anyone, edit a brief definition of "cutting against the grain", and "depilatory" with specifics as to why these are the main source of the problem. I think many readers don't quite follow exactly what the problem actually is.

Comment: @DanF I have added some edits to include the definitions of shaving against the grain as well as depilatory but as to why are they problematic that is at the heart of the question to be discussed.

Comment: Thanks for the definitions. I wasn't aware that using something such as "Nair" was problematic.

Comment: why do you think using an electric shaver is really different than using a blade? The way most electric shavers work is they first pull up the hair from the root and then cut them. this includes both pulling and cutting which is the same problem as using a metal non electric razor.

Comment: @Laser123  That is exactly the root of the point I am trying to address. Isn’t an electric razor shaving just the same as a regular razor going with the grain in the direction of hair growth. Although some authorities such as the one this article uses allow for shaving with an electric razor but not with a regular fixed blade razor.

Comment: @DannySchoemann this question is similar but not the same, that question is asking why is shaving with a razor not allowed. It’s inquiring on what halachic ground is using a razor not permissible. My question is asking why are other methods such as electric shaving and depilatory allowed when they destroy the beard just as much as shaving with a regular razor. Thank you for your efforts.